# Windows10-Ubuntu22 at the same SSD ... not bootable via USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, windows, ssd

At the beginning I used Windows on the SSD alone, than I decided to check out Ubuntu. For this I created a new partition on the same SSD and installed Ubuntu parallel beside Windows. Via GRUB I could select which OS I wanted to boot ... everything worked properly for years.
But than my laptop crashed, precisely the main board was destroyed.

Now I use an other laptop and I want to boot the same SSD via USB adapter, but it doesn't work. I installed via USB already Ubuntu at internal HDD from a stick, booted a Windows installation from another external USB stick properly, but I cannot use the WIN-Ubuntu hybrid which I described above. My old Laptop booted immediately from this SSD and presented the boot manager ... but via USB ... no chance.

Has somebody an idea how I can activate the boot process for the external Hybrid-SSD?

Comment: Windows will not boot from external USB drive. Is system UEFI or BIOS? Is Ubuntu install on SSD UEFI or BIOS? You may need settings in UEFI/BIOS. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks a lot, oldfred, for this really quick reply. Your request was a big challenge for me, because from pastebin link I had never heard before. But okay, I hope the following is what you was asking for: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/znRgy5k9q2/ .... :D . Originally the Windows and Ubuntu at the SSD was installed at UEFI system.

Comment: You are only showing an internal drive & small flash drive. External drive not shown at all. If external is UEFI it is not bootable from internal drive as it is BIOS/MBR. If UEFI, it should be bootable directly from UEFI just as you booted flash drive, but in UEFI mode, not BIOS mode.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake of course. I was so proud for having created my first pastebin link :) ... Now I tried it again and plugged in my SSD with the two OSs as external drive. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yQF744vShR/ Wherever I plug it in, internally or externally ... "No bootable device available!" is the result. But its the same SSD I used for many years in my old laptop. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: Your sda is the old BIOS/MBR configuration and sdb is the newer UEFI/gpt configuration. You can boot that way, but may have to change settings in UEFI to UEFI or to BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode to switch. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. Once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Better to have all system in UEFI mode, if using with UEFI hardware. But conversion to gpt from MBR normally totally erases drive, so good backups required. And if using UEFI, be sure to use gpt as Ubuntu may let you use MBR with UEFI, but really should not.

Comment: Thanks for these detailed explanation. But if you would look at the following report again: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WPV4yN2dMF/  you will find there a third drive ... "sdd" ... and this is a UEFI configuration too, isn't it? Why is this bootable and "sdc" is not"? This makes me so confusing ...

Comment: Because you ran report in BIOS/Legacy mode, it does not show UEFI boot entries. You can see those with `sudo efibootmgr -v` and compare partUUID with entry in UEFI. `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid` Both Windows & Ubuntu normally only install boot entries in one ESP by partUUID. Then Windows uses BCD and grub uses its menu to boot other installs. You have to do major work arounds to directly boot more than one install in either UEFI or grub.